# Which ARM based hardware is best for running ROS?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried running ROS on Beagleboard. I want to know which ARM based Hardware is preferable or Recommended to run ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10740/which-arm-based-hardware-is-best-for-running-ros?/) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2011-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there is no single answer for this question. This depend on which processes you want to run (attaching sensors, doing hardware interfacing, pointcloud processing, SLAM mapping, ...). ROS is only the framework and doesn't tell you the system load.
You should be able to install it pretty well on all ARM hardware that gives Ubuntu support and preferably has a network connection.
Look at [EROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros) for support.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2